# Runtime.exec doesn't do anything... (no errors)

Tags: java, batch-file, compilation, runtime

I am trying to use java to run a batch file at an absolute location.  The batch file will compile a couple of java files.

Here is the code which I have been trying:

```
String s=file.getAbsolutePath() + "\\compile.bat";
Runtime rut = Runtime.getRuntime();
try {
    rut.exec(new String[] {file.getAbsolutePath() + "\\compile.bat"});
}catch(IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println(s);
```

Now, when this code gets executed, I get no console errors, but the batch file is not run.  When I run the batch file through Windows Explorer, however, the batch file works, compiles the files and closes when done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you know that there were no console errors?

Try this:

```
String s=file.getAbsolutePath() + "\\compile.bat";
Runtime rut = Runtime.getRuntime();
try {
    Process process = rut.exec(new String[] {file.getAbsolutePath() + "\\compile.bat"});
    // prints out any message that are usually displayed in the console
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(process.getInputStream());
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
    }
}catch(IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: @Jeff: Don't forget to capture and read the error stream as recommended in Prince John Wesley's useful (but deleted) answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check the return value of the subprocess using `exitValue()`. 
Also read the error stream `getErrorStream()` if the exist value is non zero.

Answer (score 0):

Note that when using your invocation of [Runtime.exec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5b%5d%29), the *working directory* of the command being executed will be the *current working directory* of the java process. Does your batch file need to run in a specific directory?

If you need to set a specific working directory for the sub-process, you'll need to use another version of [Runtime.exec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5b%5d,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d,%20java.io.File%29).

Comment: Yes, the batch file is in a file folder along with all the java files which need to be compiled, so the files referenced by _javac_ are relative to the batch file's location.

Comment: Sounds like you need to specify the working directory then. Just specifying an absolute path for the _command to be executed_ **doesn't** set the working directory for the command.